# Converting xml text from webpage to json

Tags: json, xml

I'm trying to convert xml on a webpage to json.

I used axios to grab the information from the URL and then used npm xml.js to try to convert the data to json.

```
let axios = require("axios");
let convert = require("xml-js");
let mtaURL = "http://advisory.mtanyct.info/eedevwebsvc/allequipments.aspx";

axios.get(mtaURL)
.then(response => {
    let results = convert.xml2json(response, {compact: false, spaces: 4}) 
    console.log(results);
})
```

It came back with the following:

```
Error: Text data outside of root node.
Line: 0
Column: 59
Char: x
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to parse the Axios response object as XML.

You need to read the body of the response and treat **that** as XML.

```
response.data
```